# JUnit with Initialization error (eclipse oxygen)

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit5

this is the code of what i want to test

```
public class ChargeModule {
private int quantityPrn;
    private double totalCharge;
    private ArrayList<boolean[]> details;

    public ChargeModule(int quantityPrn, ArrayList<boolean[]> details) {

        this.quantityPrn = quantityPrn;
        this.details = details;
        totalCharge = 0.0;
    }

    public double getTotalCharge() {
        return totalCharge;
    }

    public int quantityPrn() {
        return quantityPrn;
    }

    public void chargeCalculation() {

        if(quantityPrn < 1 || quantityPrn > 100)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        double additionalCharge = 0.00;
        double charge = 0.00;
        double addCharge = 0.00;

        if(quantityPrn < 5)
            charge = 1.00;
        else if(quantityPrn < 10) 
            charge = 0.90;
        else if(quantityPrn < 20) 
            charge = 0.70;
        else if(quantityPrn < 50)
            charge = 0.50;
        else if(quantityPrn < 100)
            charge = 0.10;
        else
            charge = 0.10;

        for (int i = 0; i < details.size() ; i++) {
            boolean[] detail = (boolean[])details.get(i);
            boolean hqp = detail[0];
            boolean de = detail[1];

            if(hqp && de) 
                addCharge = 0.20;
            else if(!hqp && !de)
                addCharge = 0.00;
            else
                addCharge = 0.10;

            additionalCharge += addCharge;
        }

        charge *= quantityPrn;
        totalCharge = additionalCharge + charge;
}
```

this is the code for unit test

```
public class ChargeModuleUnitTest {
ChargeModule cm;
Scanner inputStream;

@Before
public void initialization() {
    String fileName = "testData.txt";
    inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

public Object[] getFileToTestTotalCharge() {
    ArrayList<boolean[]> testData;
    Object[] allTestData = new Object[2];
    String details;
    int quantity;
    double expectedValue = 0.0;

    int tt,tf,ff,ft,x=0;

    boolean[] TT = new boolean[] {true,true};
    boolean[] TF = new boolean[] {true,false};
    boolean[] FF = new boolean[] {false,false};
    boolean[] FT = new boolean[] {false,true};

    while(inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
        testData = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());

        if(inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
        details = inputStream.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = details.split(" ");

        tt = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        tf = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
        ff = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
        ft = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

        for(int i = 0; i < tt ; i++) 
            testData.add(TT);
        for(int j = 0; j < tf ; j++) 
            testData.add(TF);
        for(int k = 0; k < ff ; k++) 
            testData.add(FF);
        for(int l = 0; l < ft ; l++) 
            testData.add(FT);
        }

        if(inputStream.hasNextDouble()) 
            expectedValue = Double.parseDouble(inputStream.nextLine());

        allTestData[x] = new Object[] {quantity,testData,expectedValue};
        x++;
    }

    inputStream.close();
    return allTestData;
}

@Test
@Parameters(method = "getFileToTestTotalCharge")
public void testing(int quantity, ArrayList<boolean[]> details, double expectedValue){
    cm = new ChargeModule(quantity,details);
    cm.chargeCalculation();
    assertEquals(expectedValue,cm.getTotalCharge(),0.01);
}

@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void testasd() {
    cm = new ChargeModule(-1,null) ;
    cm.chargeCalculation();
}
```

}

this is my testData file
[testData.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltn6L.png)

this is how the error look like
[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaDgW.png)

I am confusing why it is initialization error because all the code have no problem I am confusing with maybe the parameters to have an error but I don know where it is hope someone can help me to solve this.

Comment: Could you show where you call getfileToTestTotalCharge()?

Comment: Which version of junit? JUnit4 has @Parameter but no method param and also it's not used in the test method but rather in the function that returns the params. Also JUnit5 doesn't seem to have this class

Comment: i am using junit5

Comment: and i have also added the external path to having the parameter test function

Comment: @BearSio, what makes you think you are using "JUnit 5"?

Comment: Based on the annotations in your example, you are clearly using JUnit 4.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for some reason, *@Parameter* feature doesn't work with *@Before* or *@BeforeClass* (I need to research further, but debugging it the breakpoints were never reached).

So, after that, we must keep in mind that our parameter must be especified on the class in some way, so *@Parameters* method can fetch them on each loop. Once we are using more than one parameter, we must specify which is the index of that parameter.

I also observed that it was not working fine the reading of double/float values, so I changed the file to replace "." to "," (example: 4.40 became 4,40).

Last, but not the least, when we use *@Parameterized* runner, we must just keep parameterized tests on that test case.

So, for me, the final result was like this:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ChargeModuleUnitTest {

   @Parameter(0)
   public static int quantity;

   @Parameter(1)
   public static ArrayList<boolean[]> testData;

   @Parameter(2)
   public static double expectedValue;

   public ChargeModule cm;


   @Parameters(name = "{index}: quantity = {0}, testData = {1}, expectedValue = {2}")
   public static Object[] getFileToTestTotalCharge() {
      String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Eduardo Meneses\\workspace\\StackOverflow\\src\\testData.txt";
      Scanner inputStream = null;
      try {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }

      Object[] allTestData = new Object[2];
      String details;

      int tt, tf, ff, ft, x = 0;

      boolean[] TT = new boolean[] { true, true };
      boolean[] TF = new boolean[] { true, false };
      boolean[] FF = new boolean[] { false, false };
      boolean[] FT = new boolean[] { false, true };

      while (inputStream.hasNextInt()) {
        testData = new ArrayList<boolean[]>();
        quantity = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());

        if (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {
            details = inputStream.nextLine();
            String[] tokens = details.split(" ");

            tt = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
            tf = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            ff = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            ft = Integer.parseInt(tokens[3]);

            for (int i = 0; i < tt; i++)
                testData.add(TT);
            for (int j = 0; j < tf; j++)
                testData.add(TF);
            for (int k = 0; k < ff; k++)
                testData.add(FF);
            for (int l = 0; l < ft; l++)
                testData.add(FT);
        }

        if (inputStream.hasNextDouble()){
            try {
                expectedValue = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(inputStream.nextLine()).doubleValue();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        allTestData[x] = new Object[] { quantity, testData, expectedValue };
        x++;
      }

      inputStream.close();
      return allTestData;
  }

  @Test
  public void testing() {
    cm = new ChargeModule(quantity, testData);
    cm.chargeCalculation();
    assertEquals(expectedValue, cm.getTotalCharge(), 0.01);
  }
}
```

Follow the documentation to parameterized tests: https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests

Also, [this](https://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-6-parameterized-test/) is a good example of this kind of test.

Ps.: your last test is failing.

Comment: i have added:import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)

Comment: JUnitParams-1.0.5.jar, i had import this file for parameter test

Comment: @BearSio I just edited my answer in order to make it work properly. In fact, I didn't need any jar other than the junit one, so I believe you will have no issues applying it.